# Using JavaScript to make an list to add and remove values

Tags: javascript

What I want is to be able to add and remove from a list when you click on checkboxes. I've got the adding part down but when I try to remove it will only remove the last checked one.

Ex: let's say I check 1 2 3 then uncheck 3. The list will show 1 2 but when I want to uncheck any other it will still show 1 2.

Here is a short version of the code:

```js
function updatePrice(boxElement, divToChange, innerDiv) {
            var split = boxElement.value.split("|");
            var name = split[0];
            var plusPrice = parseInt(split[1]);

            if (boxElement.checked) {
                s = document.getElementById("oneSong").innerHTML;
                s += "<div class =" + innerDiv + ">" + name + "</div>";
            }
            else {

                toReplace = "<div class =" + innerDiv + ">" + name + "</div>";
                s = s.replace(toReplace, "");
            }

            document.getElementById("oneSong").innerHTML = s;
        }
```

```html
<div class="chosenSongs" id = "chosenSongs">
                <label>Du har följande skivor:</label>
                <p class="oneSong" id = "oneSong">Här kommer valda låtar synas</p>
            </div>

<div class="title">Ringnes-Ronny</div>
                <div class="boxContainer">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Ringnes-Ronny: Polisen|59"
                            onclick="updatePrice(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Polisen<span class="time">59
                            SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Ringnes-Ronny: Valhalla|39"
                            onclick="updatePrice(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Valhalla<span class="time">39
                            SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Ringnes-Ronny: Raggare på stureplan|49"
                            onclick="updatePrice(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Raggare på stureplan<span
                            class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Ringnes-Ronny: Monster|39"
                            onclick="updatePrice(this, 'chosenSongs', 'oneSong')">Monster<span class="time">39
                            SEK</span></label>
                </div>
```

Comment: For learning, this is great. For production, this would quickly become unmaintainable without some framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than search and replace, you could regenerate the HTML each time a click happens.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let title = "Här kommer valda låtar synas",
    targ = document.querySelector('#oneSong'),
    items = document.querySelectorAll('.itemCheck');
  items.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => itemClick(e.target)))

  function itemClick(el) {
    let total = 0;
    output = [];
    items.forEach(el => {
      let s = el.value.split("|")
      if (el.checked) {
        let name = s[0];
        let price = +s[1];
        output.push(`<div class='chosenSong'>${name}</div>`);
        total += price
      }
      targ.innerHTML = title + output.join('') + `<div>Total: ${total}</div>`;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="chosenSongs" id="chosenSongs">
  <label>Du har följande skivor:</label>
  <p class="oneSong" id="oneSong"></p>
</div>

<div class="title">Ringnes-Ronny</div>
<div class="boxContainer">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class='itemCheck' value="Ringnes-Ronny: Polisen|59">Polisen<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class='itemCheck' value="Ringnes-Ronny: Valhalla|39">Valhalla<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class='itemCheck' value="Ringnes-Ronny: Raggare på stureplan|49">Raggare på stureplan<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class='itemCheck' value="Ringnes-Ronny: Monster|39">Monster<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I got back on my computer and tried your solution. It works here but not on the IDE (Visual studio code). I could be missplacing the script, cause the title "här kommer valda låtar synas" isn't showing either. I placed the script in  inside the head.

Comment: Right. It's not working because when it's in the head, it executes immediately and there isn't any HTML yet for it to reference. For that, we need to wrap it in a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...` listener (answer edited)